# Defining size for string using a variable not working properly in for loop in C

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I'm trying to reverse the string input entered by user, the problem here is in function `*rev`, when I use `size = strlen(STR);` to get the length of the string and pass it into the size of the `revS[size]` the program outputs some garbage value for reverse string! if I pass some value instead if `size` in `revS[10]` and run the program it works as expected. I Have checked the value of `size` as

```
printf("\nlength of string is: %d\n",size);
```

and it gives the correct value. I'm not getting where is it going wrong!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *rev(char *);

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter the string to reverse: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("You entered string : %s\n Reversed string is: %s", string, rev(string));
}


char *rev(char *STR)
{
    int size, i, j = 0;
    size = strlen(STR);
    printf("\nlength of string is: %d\n", size);
    char revS[size];

    for(i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        revS[j] = STR[i];
        j = j + 1;
    }

    revS[j] = '\0';
    return (revS);  
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter the string to reverse: mahaveer

length of string is: 8
You entered string : mahaveer
 Reversed string is: ╚²b
--------------------------------
Process exited after 28.7 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Don't return pointers to locals from a function. The locals are on the stack and cease to exist upon return.

Comment: You do know that `revS` is on the stack and goes out of scope

Comment: btw change `scanf("%s",string);` to `scanf("99%s",string);` to prevent buffer overruns

Comment: @EdHeal: `revS` has automatic storage duration and ceases to exist when the function returns. Scope is where a name is visible; lifetime is when an object exists. These are very different; objects may exist and be accessible from code where their names are not in scope.

Comment: @EdHeal then how does it work with **revS[8]** insted to using **revS[size]** ?

Comment: Because you're setting size to `STR`, which is a pointer

Comment: @whatthefish but when i print the size variable it gives me proper value !

Comment: even if i make another variable suppose named **int sLen = 8** and use it as size for **revS[sLen]** it doesn't work !

Comment: sorry for being simplistic.i hate this period of time. 24 hours of sunshine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your reversed string is allocated on the stack rather than the heap. When your `rev` function returns, all of the variables in that scope will be garbage collected. You can use `malloc()` to allocate memory dynamically on the heap. Note that the caller is responsible for calling `free()` on the string to avoid a memory leak.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *rev(char *);

int main() {
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter the string to reverse: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    char *r = rev(string);
    printf("You entered string: %s\nReversed string is: %s\n", string, r);
    free(r);
}

char *rev(char *str) {
    int i, j;
    int size = strlen(str);
    char *rev = malloc(sizeof(*rev) * (size + 1));

    for (i = size - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        rev[j] = str[i];
    }

    rev[size] = '\0';
    return rev;
}
```

Note that this code is susceptible to buffer overflows.

Comment: you are right but even if i print **revS** within then function **rev()**, it gives no output !

Comment: Yeah because you can't say `array[size_var]`. This is a compile-time memory allocation, and the compiler has no way of knowing what `size_var` will be, so it's just a junk value.

Comment: But compiler has the value in-hand for ``size_var`` before using it in ``array[size_var]`` , see ``size = strlen(STR);
    char revS[size];``

Comment: All that stuff is happening at runtime. Compiling happens way before that, when you do `gcc myprogram.c`. The compiler determines how much space to allocate per frame on the stack for all of a function's variables, so you're telling it to make an array with a non-initialized garbage value.

Comment: oh oke got it .

Answer (score 0):

You have tho major UBs here. First you allocate local storage array which is not available after the function return. The second one - the size is too small to accomodate the string plus terminating zero

Comment: If the size is too small to accommodate the string + terminating zero how does it work when i provide **revS[9]** instead of **size = 9; revS[size];** for input **mahaveer** which is of length 8 !

Comment: UB means that everything may happen. It may work sometimes, sometimes not.